# Obtain IP v4 address from host running Citrix XenApp

Tags: c#, network-programming, xenapp

I am writing a C# app that will run within a citrix XenApp session. The session is launched from a windows host. I am trying to get the IP v4 address of the host. The code below gets the host name correctly (first line). How do I get the IP address? I have tried this:

```
        string host_name = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%CLIENTNAME%");
        //string host_name = Dns.GetHostName();

        lblClientName.Text = host_name + Environment.NewLine;
        try
        {
            IPHostEntry ipEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(host_name);

            IPAddress[] addr = ipEntry.AddressList;
            for (int i = 0; i < addr.Length; i++)
            {
                if (addr[i].ToString().Length <= 13)
                    lblClientName.Text += addr[i].ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
IPAddress[] local = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName());
foreach (IPAddress ip in local)
{
    if (ip.AddressFamily != System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6)
        lblClientName.Text += ip.ToString();
}
```